# Using sans-serif font for chemfig

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math, chemfig

In my document, I'm currently using `chemformula` for chemical formulae. To draw reaction mechanisms I'm trying to use `chemfig`, but it's proving very difficult to get chemfig to use the same sans-serif font that `chemformula` does.

I'm using XeLaTeX as my engine so I'm using `fontspec` and `unicode-math` with it.

My document's main font is a serif font (Palatino); the math font is Cambria Math, and finally the sans-serif font is Source Sans Pro. By default `chemfig` uses math mode to typeset atoms so they will appear in my math font.

How do I get it to use my sans-serif font?

I have tried:

#### Redefining `\printatom` to use `\ch`

Does not work. This would be the best solution (I think), but I can't figure out how to get `\ch` from chemformula to accept `chemfig`'s input.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\setmathfont[version=cm]{Cambria Math}
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}
\setmathfont[version=ssp]{Source Sans Pro}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\setchemformula{format=\sffamily}
\def\printatom#1{\ch{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{C=Cl}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \atom 1 \CF
                       nodestrut
l.19 \chemfig{C=Cl}
                   ^^M
```

#### Redefining `\printatom` to use `\mathsf`

```
\def\printatom#1{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
```

It builds, but `\mathsf` doesn't use Source Sans Pro but the Unicode mathematical sans-serif characters instead (because of `unicode-math`) and I'm not sure how to get it to actually use Source Sans Pro.

#### Redefining `\printatom` to use `\mathversion`

```
\def\printatom#1{\mathversion{ssp}\ensuremath{#1}\mathversion{cm}}
```

Does not work. TikZ doesn't like `\mathversion` outside of the math block it seems, and `\mathversion` cannot be used inside math mode.

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.18 \chemfig{C=Cl}
                   ^^M
```

#### Other attempts

I also tried using `\DeclareMathAlphabet` to define Source Sans Pro as a math font, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like wrapping `\chemfig` with the appropriate `\mathversion`s works:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@@chemfig\chemfig
\def\chemfig#1{\mathversion{ssp}\@@chemfig{#1}\mathversion{cm}}
\makeatother
```